# CAShapeLayer isn't rounding corners and stroke isn't on top

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Hi guys I've creates this box, basically the corner radius isn't working & the stroke doesn't show on the top side of the shape either. Is there anyway to get this working?

```
UIBezierPath* conPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[conPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(conX, conY)];
[conPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(conX, conY+50)];
[conPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(conX+220, conY+50)];
[conPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(conX+220, conY)];

CAShapeLayer* conLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
conLayer.path = conPath.CGPath;
conLayer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
UIColor *bg = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.7];
[conLayer setFillColor:bg.CGColor];
[conLayer setStrokeColor:[UIColor grayColor].CGColor];
[[self layer] addSublayer:conLayer];
```

Comment: What happens if you add the 4th side of the shape: [conPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(conX, conY)]; followed by [conPath closePath];? (Or do bezierPathWithRect instead, saving 6 lines of code?)